# Как отследить имя последней запущенной программы резидентом assembler?

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Есть резидентная программа, которая должна отслеживать и выводить по нажатию F12 на экран имя последней запущенной программы.Подозреваю что оно лежит где-то в PSP, но не знаю где. Преподаватель сказал отслеживать функцию 4Bh прерывания 21h но я сомневаюсь что в данном случае это вообще нужно. **Пишу под tasm DOSBox 0.74-2**

Comment: Но как это сделать? В руководстве написано "функция предоставляет средства одной программе (родителю) вызвать другую программу (ребенка)", но у меня же нет родительской программы для той программы , которую  я запускаю из консоли?

Comment: Ну а как вообще действуют резиденты? Запустился, выделил себе память, пометил как резидентную, перенаправил на свой обработчик нужное прерывание, ушел. Резидентная часть обрабатывает перехваченное прерывание, если 4B - сохраняет строку в свой буфер, и в любом случае отдает оригинальному обработчику. Все. В буфере - всегда последняя запущенная программа...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не сомневайтесь. Преподаватель совершенно прав. Полного имени запускаемой программы в PSP нет, да и одна программа может вызывать другую, что затрудняет поиск нужного блока.

На то и резидент, чтоб перехватывать прерывания :) - перехватывайте 21 прерывание

```
AH = 4B
AL = 00  to load and execute program
   = 01  (Undocumented)  create program segment prefix and load
     program, but don't execute.  The CS:IP and SS:SP of the
     program is placed in parameter block.  Used by debuggers
   = 03  load program only
   = 04  called by MSC spawn() when P_NOWAIT is specified

--->>> DS:DX = pointer to an ASCIIZ filename

ES:BX = pointer to a parameter block
```

и сохраняйте эту строку во внутренний буфер. Ну, а по запросу выводите - не забывая о проблемах реентерабельности в DOS :)